# Javascript: Round Half Even last 2 digits

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

Hello expert out there,

```
var total1 = 123.44;  //how do i round this up to 123.40?
var total2 = 123.45;  //this value stay (no changes)
var total3 = 123.46;  //how do i round this up to 123.50?
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
    total = totalfromdb;  
    GST = total*6/100;  //<--- This value needed to round half even as mentioned above
    GSTadjust = ???????;  //<--- How do i get the total different from GST (round half even above)?
    grandtotal = parseInt(GST) + parseInt(total);  //<--- This value for mygrandtotal
```

The question is in the code.
How do i rounding up the .44 to .40 and .46 to .50 and/or get the different value eg:

.44 to .40, the different value is -4 (to display on page).

.46 to .50, the different value is +4 (to display on page).

The value that i need to round half even might be 123.439999999996 or 123.45999999

I've edited my question as Matti Mehtonen suggest.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you going to do with rounded values?

Comment: @MBo for Grand Total calculation

Comment: Then work with 20*x integers (added to my post)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
var round_half = function(num) {
    if ((num * 100) % 10 != 5) {
        num = (Math.round(num * 10) / 10).toFixed(2);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical sense:
`RoundANumberDownward(total * 20) / 20    //does Floor function exist in JS?`

But there are numerical issues - most of real numbers [could not be exactly represented in float formats](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), so 123.45 is stored like 123.449999999996, so rounding may produce unexpected results.

**Upd:**
You noticed in comments that you need rounded values for Grand Total calculation. Then you would better to make all calculations with 20*X **integer** values (exact arithmetics), and divide and round only the final result!

Answer (score -1):

Use
    Math.round(num * 100) / 100

Comment: i think its not possiable

Comment: Answer is simple rounding, not half-even rounding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Answer (score -1):

Check if value is divisible by 0.05. If it is, value does not need to be changed. If it's not, then you need to round that number. You can do it by multiplying value with 10, then rounding it to nearest integer and then dividing that number by 10.

```
var round = function (total) {

    if (total % 0.05 === 0) {
        return total;
    } else {
        return Math.round(total * 10) / 10;
    }
};
```

By the way, next time show what you have tried when you ask a question. :)

Comment: The divisibility check doesn't make a lot of sense in the context of binary floating-point: *no* nonzero binary floating-point value is an exact multiple of 5/100, so it's hard to predict when your `if` branch will be taken.

Comment: In fact, for binary approximations to decimal numbers with 2 digits after the point, your `if` branch will almost *never* be taken. :-)